# org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found exception, while open git repository in jGit

Tags: jgit

I'm using eclipse jgit 5.13.0.202109080827-r version and getting org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found exception while open the repository via Git.open(pathToRepo). This repository is cloned from the remote and already exists in pathToRepo, the .git metadata also available inside the directory. The pathToRepo is the directory where it contains the .git folder.

Any idea why it gives RepositoryNotFoundException even thought the repository is there?